# How to turn off js indentation warning in grunt, yeoman, angular js project setup

Tags: angularjs, emacs, gruntjs, yeoman

I originally asked for help as why grunt complains js indentation for the below code. I would like to turn off grunt's indentation rather than fixing the indentation. Is there way in grunt which will turn off indentation for js files?

I use emacs to write angular js code. I have the project setup with Yeoman and grunt. I am not sure why grunt complains about indentation for the following code -

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: '<p style="background-color:{{ color }}">Hello World</p>',
    link: function (scope, elem) {
      elem.bind('click', function () {
        // grunt warning for the following: line Expected 'elem' 
        // to have an indentation at 9   instead at 3. 
        elem.css('background-color', 'white');
      });
    }
  };
});
```

I am new to angular and have no idea why the indentation giving warning which looks ok to me. Any help on this.

Comment: A wild guess: your code contains tabs, and Emacs thinks that a tab counts as 8 spaces, but grunt thinks that a tab counts as 2 spaces.

Comment: your guess is correct! I just checked it. So I need to control the tab size only for js files (do not want to change tab size for other file mode) to avoid grunt's complain.

Comment: I do not like the idea of changing the tab size to make grunt happy. I would rather want to turn off the warning message for indentation. I am going to update my question.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's likely this is JSHint, not Grunt that's complaining - Grunt is a task runner, and JShint is a common task run to enforce coding style.

At the top of your JS file, you can put the following:

```
/* indent: 0 */
```

This will disable it per file.

You can also override this in your JSHint settings in your grunt configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

If you setup the project from [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) you can find this file `.jshintrc` in project root directory. If the file doesn't exists then you can create one.

Add the following line to the file

```
{
  "indent": false
}
```